# Dockerfile GCP Artifac Registry authentication

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

During docker image build time we try to download a Python package stored in a private GCP Artifact Registry.

We fail to authenticate with GCP since the Dockerfile does not know which account/account key is used locally.

Since we use Service Account in our CI pipeline we like to have the exact same Dockerfile for both local and CI builds.

Is there a way to share the .config/gcloud folder without actually copying it?

Comment: Which CI/CD do you use? and can you share the step where you start the container build and where the image pulling fail

Comment: Sharing the gcloud folder is not the correct approach. Your question lacks details on what you have configured and how authentication is used.

Comment: @JohnHanley We use GitLab CI runners with Service Account authentication, and locally we run gcloud auth login.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#json-key) on how to push images on artifact registry using service account json key file.